# Github Actions - GCloud app deploy app.yaml - Bucket is requester pays bucket but no user project provided

Tags: gcloud, github-actions

i have a Github actions with Gcloud, this setup worked well, after 3 months (no changes) i ran another Deployment/Action but now there is a message:

> Bucket is requester pays bucket but no user project provided.

What is the cause of this error?

I repeat, this Action worked well and no changes were made, just ran again after 3 months and failed.

My current Actions yaml is:

```
name: Deploy to GCloud

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - qa

env:
  type: prod
  PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.GCE_PROJECT }}

jobs:
  setup-deploy:
    name: Setup and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup gcloud environment
      uses: GoogleCloudPlatform/github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
      with:
        version: '290.0.1'
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCE_SA_KEY }}
        project_id: ${{ secrets.GCE_PROJECT }}

    - name: Auth helper
      run: |-
        gcloud --quiet auth configure-docker

    - name: Deploy
      run: |-
        gcloud app deploy app.${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}.yaml
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRwgO.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bucket is requester pays bucket but no user project provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739741/bucket-is-requester-pays-bucket-but-no-user-project-provided)

Comment: no because the error occurs after `gcloud app deploy app.${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}.yaml` in the proccess i don't have a POST to any endpoint or service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the link I shared in my comment says, the error you are getting is because the Requester pays is enabled in the bucket you are using to deploy. I tried at my end enabling this [feature](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-requester-pays#enable), using the below command, and I got the same error as you.

```
gsutil requesterpays set on gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

There are some considerations you must take into account to [use and access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/requester-pays#requirements) to a bucket when a Requester pays feature is enabled.

In case this feature was enabled long before you got the error and you suddenly started getting the error, or if the feature is [not enable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-requester-pays#check) in the bucket (you can execute this command to verify it `gsutil requesterpays get gs://BUCKET_NAME` and you should get something like this `gs://my-bucket: Enabled`) and you get the error, I would recommend you to open a Support case to the Google team takes a look at your issue.